# What does list[index] +1 mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have written a program to calculate the missing number in a list. The input array numbers from 1 to n, except a certain number.

I have solved this program, but I do not entirely understand how it works.

In the below program, why do we have to put +1 in `num_list[-1]+1`?

This is my code:

```
num_list =[1,2,3,4,6,7]
t = sum(range(num_list[0],num_list[-1]+1)) - sum(num_list)
print(t)
```

Here is the output:

```
5
```

Comment: `num_list[0]` is `1`. `num_list[-1]` is `7`. `num_list[-1] + 1` is `8`. Overall it's equivalent to `range(1, 8)`. There's no big secret here. Compare the output of `list(range(1, 7))` and `list(range(1, 8))`…

Comment: The second argument to `range` is `stop` and it works like an open interval, i.e. it will stop before the value. So `range(1,7)` gives you the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. This if you want it to be inclusive you need to add a number less than the `step` value. the default step is 1 hence adding 1 here so that the range also includes the number `7`.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have uploaded sums all numbers from the first number in the list until the last number by creating all numbers in between with the range(start number, end number not include) function that return range object of all the numbers then it subtracts the sum of the current list.
By this calculation, you are getting the values of the missing number

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28
- 
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 7 = 23
=
5
```

You can do the same on each list that has numbers from 1 to n and have a missing number in between.